# getting selected text in visual studio 2015 using autohotkey

Tags: c#, visual-studio, replace, comments, autohotkey

I want to find // comments then with pressing F4 , they convert to /* */.
so I need to getting selected text in visual studio 2015 using autohotkey app.
I used Active Windows Info (Window Spy) to get some info about visual studio but it doesn't give me good information about it and I couldn't get the selected text in the **VS**.
I need to write this in auto hot key.

Comment: are you sure this cant be done in VS by nature? I mean..  it's Visual Studio

Comment: it can done in VS but I want an ahk becasue you can use it in VS and other IDE too one macro for many app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I couldn't get the selected text in the VS

Getting the selected text in the active application is usually done like this in Ahk:

```
clipboard_backup := clipboardAll
send ^c ; copy
clipwait
SELECTED_TEXT := clipboard
clipboard := clipboard_backup
```

Not explicitly tested, but it should give you an idea

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution

```
F4::
TempCB = %ClipBoard%
ClipBoard = ; Clear clipboard
Send, ^c
Sleep, 100 ; Wait 0.1 seconds for clipboard (clipboard will not get filled if nothing is selected)
if (Clipboard = "")
{
    Send, {Home}+{End}^c ; Select line and copy to clipbard
}
SelectedLine = %ClipBoard%
pos := RegExMatch(SelectedLine,"\/\/",found)
if(found = "//"){
Str := RegExReplace(SelectedLine,"`r`n$","")
Str := RegExReplace(Str,"\/\/","/*")
Str .= " */"
Send, {Home}+{End}^x
ClipBoard = %Str%
Send, {Raw}%Str%
}
ClipBoard = %TempCB% ; Restore (text part) of previous clipboard content.
Return
```